# Android application different style titles in same title bar

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I have an application where the requirement is to show the application version name on the right corner of the application title bar.

Is this possible?

Note that the version name is different color and different size also.

sorry cannot post an image because of not enough reputation.... :(

It is something like

```
--------------------------------------------------
Application title comes here...              v1.23
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I found something close that I can use, its this code: `setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>"+Your Title+"</small>"))` but it only seem to allow basic html tags. If it had allowed styling on advanced level, may be I could have used float left and right to show what I needed to.

Comment: Have created a snippet on jsfiddle using pure HTML and CSS. Might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/samir_s/g6py4run/

Comment: thanks for the effort @samir but it looks like the Html.fromHtml() does not support much html tags or css styles [on this link scroll down to: Tags Supported by Html.fromHtml()](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like impossible to do that.

The only workaround appears to be using a custom title bar as mentioned in this post [android place a textview over application title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646210/android-place-a-textview-over-application-title)

Code below for quick help:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if ( customTitleSupported ) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
        }

        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        if ( myTitleText != null ) {
            myTitleText.setText("MY TITLE");
        }


    }
```

hope it helps somebody!