# android place a textview over application title

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to place a textbox over the application title bar? like in xcode, it is possible to place a textbox anywhere I guess using absolute positioning...

The aim is to put a small version indicator on the top right corner of the application title bar.

Thanks

Comment: can somebody tell me the reason for -ve reputation...? so that I keep in mind when asking questions next time.

Comment: You can make your custom title bar, then add something upper or make full screen app, then place your text wherever you want.

Comment: Imran Ahmed: Use custom layout for Activity title to add version indicator in title bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below one.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if ( customTitleSupported ) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
        }

        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        if ( myTitleText != null ) {
            myTitleText.setText("MY TITLE");
        }


    }
```

Comment: thanks... this worked for me! Although the question costed me all the reputation I had... :(